# The 'Always Allow' button not showed when accessing keychain

Tags: macos, keychain

While I was archiving iOS package through XCode, it told me that it needed to access system keychain. So, I put in my account and password then pushed the 'Allow' button, But soon it asked me again.

I know the 'Always Allow' button is right choice, but that choice did not appear at the place it should be!

[image]
The image shows the information in Chinese. Only buttons of 'Deny' and 'Allow' appear.

Maybe I have changed the system configuration in the past, but I can not remember. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 10):

try to draw your distribution certificate from "system" item to "login" item in keyChain